# Bash string variables have unpredictable change when used

Tags: python, bash

I get cookie "encrypted_value" from chrome cookies file, and decode, but one of string variable, it appears unexpected changes when I use it.

**If you output direct:**

```
echo "$SEID"
```

**output is:**

```
aa312d7a2a15ab67a16f39495dbc22bf9930dafaf70b3eddbd955b0fb39bd7ef661af6ac15d0d98fbbc179c9d6e85901b56c2c4efd9a40df013060d7
```

**when I did this:**

```sh
echo "$SEID;"
```

**but output changed, you should see the penultimate eighth character changed from zero to semicolon!!!**

```
aa312d7a2a15ab67a16f39495dbc22bf9930dafaf70b3eddbd955b0fb39bd7ef661af6ac15d0d98fbbc179c9d6e85901b56c2c4efd9a40df;13060d7
```

my value come from this script:

```sh
SEID=$(get_cookies_from_chrome "xxxx.com" "SEID")
```

`get_cookies_from_chrome` is this:

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
#coding=utf-8 

import os 
import sys
import sqlite3 
import keyring 
from Crypto.Cipher import AES 
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2

my_pass = keyring.get_password('Chrome Safe Storage', 'Chrome') 
my_pass = my_pass.encode('utf8') 
iterations = 1003 
cookie_file = os.path.expanduser('~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Cookies') 

salt = b'saltysalt' 
length = 16 
iv = b' ' * length 

class ChromeCookies:
    @staticmethod
    def aes_decrypt(token): 
        key = PBKDF2(my_pass, salt, length, iterations) 
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv) 
        dec_token = cipher.decrypt(token) 
        return dec_token 

    @staticmethod
    def query_cookies(host_key, name): 
        with sqlite3.connect(cookie_file) as conn: 
            sql = 'select encrypted_value from cookies where host_key="%s" and name = "%s"' % (host_key, name)
        result = conn.execute(sql).fetchall() 
        return result 

    @staticmethod
    def get_value(host_key, name):
        result = ChromeCookies.query_cookies(host_key, name)
        if len(result) != 0:
            return ChromeCookies.aes_decrypt(result[0][0][3:]).decode('utf-8')
        else:
            return None


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    print(ChromeCookies.get_value(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
```

Comment: I solved this, `re.sub("[^{}]+".format(printable), "", result)`, use this code process my string, I don't known why get so many invisible character.

Answer (score 0):

`echo "$SEID;"` *will* print the value of the `SEID` variable followed by a semicolon, followed by a newline. The reason you're seeing what you're seeing is that the Python script prints some non-printable characters which have special meaning in the current terminal - they make the cursor (the thing which decides where on the screen to put the next character) to *move* before printing the semicolon.

To see the non-printable characters try escaping the characters by running for example `get_cookies_from_chrome "xxxx.com" "SEID" | xxd`.

Comment: already try, sees normal, problem character hexadecimal code is 30, is means '0'

Comment: You'll be interested in the characters *before* it, which would change the cursor position. Can you post the output of this?

Answer (score 0):

Your script must be generating text with a CR character, see [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/1745001). For example if your script output `123456789\rabcde` and you saved it in SEID then `echo "$SEID"` would output what **looks like** `abcde6789` and then `echo "$SEID;"` would output what looks like `abcde;789`

Comment: It seems process file content, I have no idea how process variable.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that means.

Comment: I add `.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')` in *get_cookies_from_chrome*, to process my result, but not working.

Comment: All I can tell you is what your problem is, I won't be able to help you debug your python script, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for help, I add `.replace('\b', '')` in *get_cookies_from_chrome*, is works....